# How to find gld_throughput and gst_throughput using nv-nsight-cu-cli

Tags: nsight-compute

Not able to get it working and documentation is bit tricky to read. 
Tried below and see the outputs as n/a.

```
root@teja:~/Projs/CUDA/05-Profiling# nv-nsight-cu-cli --device 0 --metrics gst_throughput,gld_throughput ./run 0
==PROF== Connected to process 28170 (/root/Projs/CUDA/05-Profiling/run)
==PROF== Profiling "Init" - 1: 0%....50%....100% - 1 pass
==PROF== Profiling "Transpose_rowRead_colWrite" - 2: 0%....50%....100% - 1 pass
==PROF== Disconnected from process 28170
[28170] run@127.0.0.1
  Init(mat<int>,mat<int>), 2020-May-01 14:35:43, Context 1, Stream 7
    Section: Command line profiler metrics
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------- ------------------------------
    gld_throughput                                                                                                (!) n/a
    gst_throughput                                                                                                (!) n/a
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------- ------------------------------

  Transpose_rowRead_colWrite(mat<int>,mat<int>), 2020-May-01 14:35:43, Context 1, Stream 7
    Section: Command line profiler metrics
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------- ------------------------------
    gld_throughput                                                                                                (!) n/a
    gst_throughput                                                                                                (!) n/a
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------- ------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

The names got changed with the Nsight Compute tool.

This table helped to get the new names: https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-compute/2019.5/NsightComputeCli/index.html#nvprof-metric-comparison

Used following cmd to get it working.

```
nv-nsight-cu-cli --metrics l1tex__t_bytes_pipe_lsu_mem_global_op_ld.sum.per_second,l1tex__t_sectors_pipe_lsu_mem_global_op_ld.sum,l1tex__t_bytes_pipe_lsu_mem_global_op_st.sum.per_second,l1tex__t_sectors_pipe_lsu_mem_global_op_st.sum, ./<program>
```